# Scikit-image: How can I ignore / mask zero values from ndarray for interpolating afterwards?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image

As you can see my question above, I would like to mask / ignore the zero values from a ndarray, which I would like to interpolate afterwards. I hope you can help me with this, because I am trying since many days to solve this problem.

**What do I want?**

I have many ndarrays with different length sizes, which I would like to interpolate, let's say in this case, to make it smaller.

**This is how one of these arrays looks like:**

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 144.0, 144.0, 145.0, 145.0, 144.0, 143.0, 143.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

As you can see, it is always one row (let's call it "array_row"), with many elements (for this example I just wrote an array example with 15 elements)

**How do I interpolate?**

I am using the scikit-image resize method, like this:

```
new_array = skimage.transform.resize(array_row, (1, 10))
```

The result of this interpolation looks something like this:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 71.49999999, 144.0, 144.60344827, 145.0, 144.70896278, 143.0, 71.49999999, 0.0, 0.0]
```

When using the interpolation, this result is ok like this. The value "71.49999999" is because of the zero value before and / or after the non-zero values, which is normal.

But for my case, I do not want that this happens. I would like to let `skimage.transform.resize` to ignore the zero values, so that the result would be something like this:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 144.0, 144.0, 144.60344827, 145.0, 144.70896278, 143.0, 143.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The values should not be changed (or at least only from the non-zero value next to it).

I actually have no idea on how to do that. I tried something like masking and giving the masked  indices the value "255", which also does not give the result as expected.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 4):

The scikit-image functions expect a regularly spaced grid of values, but there are other interpolators in scipy that allow more freedom.  E.g., consider a cubic interpolator, that takes input coordinates and values as input:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


y = np.array([150, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 144.0, 144.0, 145.0, 145.0, 144.0, 143.0, 143.0, 0.0, 0.0, 148])
x = np.arange(len(y))
x_ = np.linspace(0, 14, 100)
mask = (y != 0)

p = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
p_masked = interpolate.interp1d(x[mask], y[mask], kind='cubic')

plt.plot(x, y, 'x-', label='Input')
plt.plot(x_, p(x_), label='Interpolated')
plt.plot(x_, p_masked(x_), label='Interpolated (ignoring zeros)')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('/tmp/cubic_interpolation.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image: cubic interpolation with and without masking]

For this approach, you will need to specify the end-points, because it does not extrapolate.  Radial basis functions will work better for extrapolation, but will also tend to fall back down to zero in regions without data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So far it looks good. But one question still remains: Is it possible to interpolate and to resize the array to a specific size? In my example I had 15 elements in it, but after interpolation and resizing I would like to have it for example 10 elements in it. I would like to change the width so that I can make it smaller or even bigger. Do you have any idea on how to approach that?

Comment: You can call the interpolator on as many or as few coordinates as you like.  The code shows how that works, e.g., when I call the interpolator only on masked points.